# How do I create multiple groups from one SVG so a function can be assigned by clicking different parts of the SVG?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

[image: Screenshot of highlighted portion]

[image]

[image]

I'm working on dental software and I have an SVG for each square below (each square represents a tooth).

I'm trying to understand/find a way to create separate groups for each part of the SVG, similar to how the green part of the square is hilighted in green, to indicate a filling will be placed in that portion of the tooth. The intended use is for a web-based piece of software.

The goal is to have an SVG but with separate portions (or groups) so that a function can be assigned to the sections individually as opposed to being treated as a single unit.

I have taken a few screenshots to demonstrate from existing software.

I have also added a screenshare on illustrator demonstrating the difficulty with having a path in which part of the path needs to be invisible. Whenever I try to select just part of the path to adjust the selected part in isolation, the changes are applied to the whole path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would need groups to do this. If I have understood your question properly, I think all you really need are separate shapes (closed paths) which you can then fill by changing the fill attribute.

One way to do this would be to draw two squares, one inside the other, and draw the adjoining lines to the corners. For your strokes, it's probably best to use the rounded corner and rounded end caps options to make this task easier, then you won't have any weird corner mitres to fix.

Like this

[image]

The stroke settings as follows

[image]

Now select all the pieces, and use the Shape Builder tool, and click on each area to turn these into fillable pieces. Then select one of them and change the fill.

Like this

[image]

**Edit** For more complex designs you could have separate outlines (with no fill), and separate objects for the fillable areas with fill and no stroke.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. Much appreciated. Sorry, i think i didn't explain very clearly. 

The reason we want groups is because the SVG will end up in a web app. We need hoverable sections, so that when the mouse hovers over a particular part of the square (tooth), we can add either a filling or note that there is decay in that part of the tooth specifically. I've edited to add a photo and show a different perspective.

Comment: I think this should work for you.  Each piece is a separate object - a closed path. All you need to do is change the fill attribute of that path to make it green.  You don't need groups to do this.  Groups are a way of grouping multiple paths. Since each of these pieces will a separate object (just one path), then you don't need a group.  You could of course group the whole graphic, but adding a fill attribute to a group would change the fill in all the paths in that group.

Comment: I think it may work for the square, the root graphic (attached above) however has a path which we can see hilighted when we hover over that part of the root but with no visible closed path. It'd be great to know how to create a path without having the whole outline of the path visible to the user, as above.

Comment: I have added a screen recording to demonstrate the issue. Hope this helps. Thank you again.

Comment: @SJKhalaf - Not sure if that helps. Do you want to make the stroke and fill separate shapes?  That is certainly possible. [see here](https://imgur.com/xn8164P).  This is really the same solution - just separating the outline from the fill, so that each is it's own object.

Comment: @SJKhalaf - I've edited the answer to add this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139918/discussion-between-billy-kerr-and-s-j-khalaf).

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Much appreciated.